# JavaScript: it works, but what is a more efficient way to write this function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, loops, if-statement

Is there a better way to do this than using so many `else if` statements?

> Enter a string into the input box below. If the string starts with:
>
> "a" or "A" "starts with A" should be displayed. "b" or "B" "starts
>   with B" should be displayed. "c" or "C" "starts with C" should be
>   displayed. "d" or "D" "starts with D" should be displayed. "e" or "E"
>   "starts with E" should be displayed. anything else "starts with
>   something else" should be displayed.

```
function startsWith(input) {
    if(input==='a' || input==='A') {
        return ("starts with A");
    }
    else if(input==='b' || input==='B') {
        return ("starts with B");
    }
    else if(input==='c' || input==='C') {
        return ("starts with C");
    }
    else if(input==='d' || input==='D') {
        return ("starts with D");
    }
    else if(input==='e' || input==='E') {
        return ("starts with E");
    }
    else {
        return ("starts with something else");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
function startsWith(input) {
    start = input[0].toUpperCase();
    if (start < 'F' && start >= 'A') {
        return "starts with " + start;
    }
    return "starts with something else";
}
```

Comment: Lol you can't do `<  'F'`

Comment: Yes, you can @EdwinReynoso.

Comment: This function breaks unfortunately on things like `startsWith("1sfafas")`.

Comment: @EvanKnowles, fixed ^_^

Comment: probably because I've never done that and now that I think about it I may have with variables and not even realizing when it comes to `Array#sort`

Comment: `Array#sort` should use the natural sort order anyways - this works thanks to JavaScript loosely typing.

Comment: @EvanKnowles what if I threw an 'Invalid Input' for datatypes like ("1sfafas")? Would that make sense?

Comment: I was using a compare function for something more complicated

Comment: @zachc That depends on the requirements - from what you provided, the answers appear correct.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead (which also checks the first character)

```
function startsWith(input) {
  return "starts with " + (input[0].toLowerCase() >= 'a' && input[0].toLowerCase() <= 'e' ? input[0].toUpperCase() : 'something else');
}
```

Comment: why call `.toUpperCase()` over and over just save it to a variable.

Comment: I just wanted a one liner ;)

Comment: oh ok but yea your ternary operator is what makes it an good one liner, so for performance wise save to a variable.